# Saving data relationship with sync doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

Hello everyone i am newly in laravel and i do not know to to save data with modules and permission.This is my table 
[image]

and this is Request.

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "role_id": "2",
    "module_id": [1,2],
    "permission_id": [[1,2],[1,2]]
}
```

and am saving like this

```
$user_id = $request->user_id;
$role_id = $request->role_id;
$module_id = $request->module_id;
$permission_id = $request->permission_id;
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user->permissions()->sync($permission_id);
```

Comment: `sync` is available for ManyToMany relation. From your table structure it seems you have oneToMany relation. So, you can use `$user->permissions()->create(['module_id' => $module_id, 'permission_id' => $permission_id]);`

Comment: @rkj thanks for reply ,i have replace with your code to my code  $user->permissions()->sync($syncData);  To   $user->permissions()->create(['module_id' => $module_id, 'permission_id' => $permission_id]); but am geting still error

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'module_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `permissions` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-07-31 12:01:01, 2018-07-31 12:01:01))",

Comment: check does you have value for module_id ?

Comment: am sending this Request from postman


{
    "user_id": "1",
    "role_id": "2",
    "module_id": [1,2],
    "permission_id": [[1,2],[1,2]]
}

Comment: i have use this in User Model

public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','module_permissions')->withTimestamps();
    }

Comment: see, when you have more than 2 foreign key in pivot table then better use `hasMany` relationship because if you use `ManyToMany` relationship then you can't load third relationship with eager loading

Comment: ok one more things @rkj can i use hasMany instead of belongsToMany ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177094/discussion-between-gorakh-yadav-and-rkj).

Comment: SO is not somewhere you ask for an answer then others must give you the complete solution you can use straight away. And you don't downvote others' answers for not getting the solution from them. Your question is poorly described and I strongly suggest you to consider what you are doing with your downvotes. You don't deserve those reputations.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Laravel >5.5 I think you will be able to use the model_has_permissions table.

Install the permissions package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-permissions-via-roles

Create a Model called Module, import the hasRoles Trait:

```
use HasRoles;
```

Then you should be able to use the syncRoles() syncPermissions() methods for this model.
I'm not very sure if you are talking about this sort of permissions. If so, do not reinvent the wheel at this stage.

As you use this package more along the way you develop your program, dig into the trait and the controllers of this package, you will then learn how the syncRoles method work and hence you will know how to write your own code to sync a Many to Many relationship.

Comment: this one is different way that am asking

Comment: When you downvote an answer simply because the answer doesn't give you the solution straight away, you should consider quit stackoverflow